# returning variable from EndInvoke

Tags: javascript, c#, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a method that runs in it's own thread via BeginInvoke.

```
caller.BeginInvoke(pId, sID.Value, pi, vIRB, a, sls, aspNetUserID.Value, pbID, CreateComplete, caller);
```

The CreateComplete method is the callback it does after it's done.

```
    private void CreateComplete(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        Caller caller = (Caller)result.AsyncState;
        string fileName = caller.EndInvoke(result);
    }
```

It generates a file that needs to be downloaded. Before I threaded things I returned the file path to javascript and had it open a window to that location to download the file.

I tried storing it as a Session variable, passing the HTTPContext.Current to the BeginInvoke method, but that is null when it arrives.

How can I save the returned file path so that I can do something similar in the new threaded system.

Edit: The threading allows me to update the user on the progress of the process with a progress bar and little updated messages. I am not doing it just for fun. :)

Comment: Don't do that.  Jumping to a different threadpool thread just slows things down.

Comment: Well, the thing takes so long I wanted to have a progress bar. So, there is a second thread that pings for updates from the main thread for the progress bar to work.